# data disappear on after pageload on next month click in full Calender

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

i have implemented jquery full calender to show the event i.e http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar.i have write ajax post method to fetch data on document.ready() from controller in mvc.Its working fine.But as i have clicked on next month button,the rendered data has been lost and only empty calender is showing.

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste your ajax request here. so that some one can debug and your code for fullcalendar.
If possible do a jsfiddle